# Стек технологий JavaEE

Tags: java

Приветствую! Я сейчас закрываю пробелы в Java Core, знаю Spring ioc и немного hibernate и хочу начать писать свой проект. Хотелось бы также сделать хорошую frontend часть, но я не могу определиться с технологиями. Какой стек технологий в приоритете используется на сегодняшний день и действительно ли надо знать javascript+html+css для javaee разработчика?

Comment: Непонятно зачем javaee-разработчику spring ioc. А javascrpt+thml+css пригодится для общей эрудиции, чтобы не замыкаться в своём болоте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В наше время грешно не знать js, html и css. Тем более, что знать там особо нечего. Что касается стека технологий Java, ответ на ваш вопрос написан в его заголовке. Хотя бы в основах надо знать всё, что входит в JavaEE.

Answer (score 1):

Для чего писать, если под вэб, то знание этих технологий необходимо для понимания кода. Если вы уже говорите о фронтенде то необходимо определиться какой он у вас будет одностраничный, многостраничный, или гибридный. В общем-то все зависит от того, какой фраймворк использовать. А это делается путем изучения отдельных фрейворков. Там же определяется и стэк технологий. Поскольку выбор фреймворков и технологий делается сугубо индивидуально, то вам лучше решать *что* именно вам подходит для вашего проекта.